# Flow error `indexer property is missing in undefined`

Tags: flowtype

Error:

Cannot get `keys[key]` because an indexer property is missing in undefined

Code:

```
export type Keys = {
  [string]: string,
  id?: number,
  href?: string,
  expand?: Array<string>
}

const keys: Keys = {
};

const requiredKeys: Array<string> = ['aa'];
let keyedUrl: string = 'hi/:aa/test';

function a(keys?: Keys) {
  requiredKeys.forEach((key: string) => {
    keyedUrl = keyedUrl.replace(`:${key}`, keys[key]);
    delete keys[key];
  });
}

a(keys);
```

[Live Example](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDSxEGc4F44DeAUHHANpYxQCWAdgOYC6AXHJTQwDQlzUAmAfla0ArgFsARsCjdSACyjAAZkLZU69WXFBgAhrUGsAglCi7EAHnYaAfEQC+RIgGMItSnADWmLKwzY8QgcAbidXd3hFAEcRakU+f184EzNLawYbQLIAcl1dbMZQgBtgeG9EYD4AVSgi1nT6QOy5agB6ZjzWmGBKbNCiJRFaZxhqNzhdAApyrFVEgEog0mjY+MSAOiVoAFFdZzlJ6cx69QZF3EziUlJyypqiwNvq2vXFMCK94EmAA2YAEgI5Xs304Xh8ZHKjHmoWucD4wBK3TB2AhmEKPHs0IcTimMyxQA)

How do I fix this?

Comment: You've defined `keys?: Keys` as optional, so it can be undefined. You can wrap arrow function body inside `forEach` with `if (keys)` condition.